# Trying to install java JDK every time I install/remove anything

Tags: installation, apt, java, uninstall, jdk

I have installed java JDK following this tutorial:

http://www.duinsoft.nl/packages.php?t=en

The installation was ok but every time I install or uninstall anything, I get this message:

```
Downloading...
--2012-08-08 22:12:26--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com... 201.48.47.25, 201.48.47.27 Connecting
to download.oracle.com|201.48.47.25|:80... connected. HTTP request
sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily Location:
https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
[following]
--2012-08-08 22:12:26--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com... 23.62.50.174 Connecting to
edelivery.oracle.com|23.62.50.174|:443... connected. HTTP request
sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily Location:
http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
[following]
--2012-08-08 22:12:27--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com|201.48.47.25|:80... connected. HTTP
request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 5307 (5.2K)
[text/html] Saving to: `./jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz'

      0K .....                                                 100%  416K=0.01s

2012-08-08 22:12:27 (416 KB/s) - `./jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz' saved
[5307/5307]

Download done. sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz Oracle JDK
7 is NOT installed. dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer
(--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned
error exit status 1 Setting up firefox
(14.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ... Please restart all running
instances of firefox, or you will experience problems. Setting up
firefox-globalmenu (14.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ... Errors were
encountered while processing:  oracle-java7-installer E: Sub-process
/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have checked my **sources.list** and the is no reference to this.

How to remove this code from trying to install it every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved, running these commands:

Just looking for any Java installer I found it in this directory and removed it

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
```

Run this if you have any Java repository on your sources.list, it was not my case.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Just a warning for others: Don't modify or delete files in `/var/lib/dpkg` unless you're absolutely sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, I did that because I new what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Java isn't installing correctly so every time you try to install something, apt attempts to fix that package. Looking at the output there it's failing to download (every time it downloads the java package, it is corrupt). You have two options.

1) Keep letting it try until it finally successfully downloads the package. 
2) Uninstall oracle-java7-installer